# SQL Server 2005 - query complex XML (SOAP Response)

Tags: xml

I want to use SQL Server to query an XML file in such a way to turn the following XML sample, as a flat table:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
  <ns1:getArtifactDetailListResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://schema.open.collab.net/sfee50/soap60/service">
  <getArtifactDetailListReturn href="#id0" /> 
  </ns1:getArtifactDetailListResponse>
  <multiRef id="id0" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns2:ArtifactDetailSoapList" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns2="http://schema.open.collab.net/sfee50/soap60/type">
  <dataRows soapenc:arrayType="ns2:ArtifactDetailSoapRow[4]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
  <dataRows href="#id1" /> 
  <dataRows href="#id2" /> 
  <dataRows href="#id3" /> 
  <dataRows href="#id4" /> 
  </dataRows>
  <fullListSize xsi:type="xsd:int">4</fullListSize> 
  </multiRef>
  <multiRef id="id2" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns3:ArtifactDetailSoapRow" xmlns:ns3="http://schema.open.collab.net/sfee50/soap60/type" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <actualEffort xsi:type="xsd:int">0</actualEffort> 
  <artifactGroup xsi:type="xsd:string" /> 
  <assignedToFullname xsi:type="xsd:string">Anon User</assignedToFullname> 
  <assignedToUsername xsi:type="xsd:string">anon_user</assignedToUsername> 
  <autosumming xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</autosumming> 
  <category xsi:type="xsd:string">Internal Improvement</category> 
  <closeDate xsi:type="xsd:dateTime" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <customer xsi:type="xsd:string" /> 
  <description xsi:type="xsd:string">Description Here</description> 
  <estimatedEffort xsi:type="xsd:int">0</estimatedEffort> 
  <flexFields href="#id5" /> 
  <folderId xsi:type="xsd:string">tracker15657</folderId> 
  <folderPathString xsi:type="xsd:string">tracker.brd_new_request</folderPathString> 
  <folderTitle xsi:type="xsd:string">BRDs (New/Change Requests)</folderTitle> 
  <id xsi:type="xsd:string">artf705037</id> 
  <lastModifiedDate xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2013-02-01T10:43:02.000Z</lastModifiedDate> 
  <planningFolderId xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <planningFolderTitle xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <points xsi:type="xsd:int">0</points> 
  <priority xsi:type="xsd:int">4</priority> 
  <projectId xsi:type="xsd:string">proj7173</projectId> 
  <projectPathString xsi:type="xsd:string">projects.rapid_application_developmet</projectPathString> 
  <projectTitle xsi:type="xsd:string">Rapid Application Development</projectTitle> 
  <remainingEffort xsi:type="xsd:int">0</remainingEffort> 
  <reportedInReleaseId xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <reportedInReleaseTitle xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <resolvedInReleaseId xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <resolvedInReleaseTitle xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <status xsi:type="xsd:string">RAD Reviewing</status> 
  <statusClass xsi:type="xsd:string">Open</statusClass> 
  <submittedByFullname xsi:type="xsd:string">Anon User</submittedByFullname> 
  <submittedByUsername xsi:type="xsd:string">anon_user</submittedByUsername> 
  <submittedDate xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2013-02-01T10:43:02.000Z</submittedDate> 
  <title xsi:type="xsd:string">SWAPS - Weekly Tracer Exception Report</title> 
  <trackerIcon xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <version xsi:type="xsd:int">100</version> 
  </multiRef>
  <multiRef id="id1" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns4:ArtifactDetailSoapRow" xmlns:ns4="http://schema.open.collab.net/sfee50/soap60/type" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <actualEffort xsi:type="xsd:int">0</actualEffort> 
  <artifactGroup xsi:type="xsd:string" /> 
  <assignedToFullname xsi:type="xsd:string">Anon User</assignedToFullname> 
  <assignedToUsername xsi:type="xsd:string">anon_user</assignedToUsername> 
  <autosumming xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</autosumming> 
  <category xsi:type="xsd:string">Internal Improvement</category> 
  <closeDate xsi:type="xsd:dateTime" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <customer xsi:type="xsd:string" /> 
  <description xsi:type="xsd:string">KOP embelished for internal improvement/automation.</description> 
  <estimatedEffort xsi:type="xsd:int">0</estimatedEffort> 
  <flexFields href="#id6" /> 
  <folderId xsi:type="xsd:string">tracker15657</folderId> 
  <folderPathString xsi:type="xsd:string">tracker.brd_new_request</folderPathString> 
  <folderTitle xsi:type="xsd:string">BRDs (New/Change Requests)</folderTitle> 
  <id xsi:type="xsd:string">artf705038</id> 
  <lastModifiedDate xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2013-02-01T10:49:14.000Z</lastModifiedDate> 
  <planningFolderId xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <planningFolderTitle xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <points xsi:type="xsd:int">0</points> 
  <priority xsi:type="xsd:int">4</priority> 
  <projectId xsi:type="xsd:string">proj7173</projectId> 
  <projectPathString xsi:type="xsd:string">projects.rapid_application_developmet</projectPathString> 
  <projectTitle xsi:type="xsd:string">Rapid Application Development</projectTitle> 
  <remainingEffort xsi:type="xsd:int">0</remainingEffort> 
  <reportedInReleaseId xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <reportedInReleaseTitle xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <resolvedInReleaseId xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <resolvedInReleaseTitle xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <status xsi:type="xsd:string">RAD Reviewing</status> 
  <statusClass xsi:type="xsd:string">Open</statusClass> 
  <submittedByFullname xsi:type="xsd:string">Anon User</submittedByFullname> 
  <submittedByUsername xsi:type="xsd:string">anon_user</submittedByUsername> 
  <submittedDate xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2013-02-01T10:49:14.000Z</submittedDate> 
  <title xsi:type="xsd:string">SWAPS   Weekly Trade Support Report</title> 
  <trackerIcon xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <version xsi:type="xsd:int">100</version> 
  </multiRef>
  <multiRef id="id4" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns5:ArtifactDetailSoapRow" xmlns:ns5="http://schema.open.collab.net/sfee50/soap60/type" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <actualEffort xsi:type="xsd:int">0</actualEffort> 
  <artifactGroup xsi:type="xsd:string" /> 
  <assignedToFullname xsi:type="xsd:string">Anon User</assignedToFullname> 
  <assignedToUsername xsi:type="xsd:string">anon_user</assignedToUsername> 
  <autosumming xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</autosumming> 
  <category xsi:type="xsd:string">Internal Improvement</category> 
  <closeDate xsi:type="xsd:dateTime" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <customer xsi:type="xsd:string" /> 
  <description xsi:type="xsd:string">BRD submitted for internal automation of BAU.</description> 
  <estimatedEffort xsi:type="xsd:int">0</estimatedEffort> 
  <flexFields href="#id7" /> 
  <folderId xsi:type="xsd:string">tracker15657</folderId> 
  <folderPathString xsi:type="xsd:string">tracker.brd_new_request</folderPathString> 
  <folderTitle xsi:type="xsd:string">BRDs (New/Change Requests)</folderTitle> 
  <id xsi:type="xsd:string">artf704445</id> 
  <lastModifiedDate xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2013-01-30T16:31:35.000Z</lastModifiedDate> 
  <planningFolderId xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <planningFolderTitle xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <points xsi:type="xsd:int">0</points> 
  <priority xsi:type="xsd:int">4</priority> 
  <projectId xsi:type="xsd:string">proj7173</projectId> 
  <projectPathString xsi:type="xsd:string">projects.rapid_application_developmet</projectPathString> 
  <projectTitle xsi:type="xsd:string">Rapid Application Development</projectTitle> 
  <remainingEffort xsi:type="xsd:int">0</remainingEffort> 
  <reportedInReleaseId xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <reportedInReleaseTitle xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <resolvedInReleaseId xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <resolvedInReleaseTitle xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <status xsi:type="xsd:string">RAD Reviewing</status> 
  <statusClass xsi:type="xsd:string">Open</statusClass> 
  <submittedByFullname xsi:type="xsd:string">Anon User</submittedByFullname> 
  <submittedByUsername xsi:type="xsd:string">anon_user</submittedByUsername> 
  <submittedDate xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2013-01-30T16:29:02.000Z</submittedDate> 
  <title xsi:type="xsd:string">SWAPS Daily MIS Overall Performance</title> 
  <trackerIcon xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <version xsi:type="xsd:int">101</version> 
  </multiRef>
  <multiRef id="id3" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns6:ArtifactDetailSoapRow" xmlns:ns6="http://schema.open.collab.net/sfee50/soap60/type" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <actualEffort xsi:type="xsd:int">0</actualEffort> 
  <artifactGroup xsi:type="xsd:string" /> 
  <assignedToFullname xsi:type="xsd:string">Anon User</assignedToFullname> 
  <assignedToUsername xsi:type="xsd:string">anon_user</assignedToUsername> 
  <autosumming xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</autosumming> 
  <category xsi:type="xsd:string">Internal Improvement</category> 
  <closeDate xsi:type="xsd:dateTime" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <customer xsi:type="xsd:string" /> 
  <description xsi:type="xsd:string">BRD submitted for internal automation of BAU.</description> 
  <estimatedEffort xsi:type="xsd:int">0</estimatedEffort> 
  <flexFields href="#id8" /> 
  <folderId xsi:type="xsd:string">tracker15657</folderId> 
  <folderPathString xsi:type="xsd:string">tracker.brd_new_request</folderPathString> 
  <folderTitle xsi:type="xsd:string">BRDs (New/Change Requests)</folderTitle> 
  <id xsi:type="xsd:string">artf704570</id> 
  <lastModifiedDate xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2013-01-31T10:27:13.000Z</lastModifiedDate> 
  <planningFolderId xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <planningFolderTitle xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <points xsi:type="xsd:int">0</points> 
  <priority xsi:type="xsd:int">4</priority> 
  <projectId xsi:type="xsd:string">proj7173</projectId> 
  <projectPathString xsi:type="xsd:string">projects.rapid_application_developmet</projectPathString> 
  <projectTitle xsi:type="xsd:string">Rapid Application Development</projectTitle> 
  <remainingEffort xsi:type="xsd:int">0</remainingEffort> 
  <reportedInReleaseId xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <reportedInReleaseTitle xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <resolvedInReleaseId xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <resolvedInReleaseTitle xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <status xsi:type="xsd:string">RAD Reviewing</status> 
  <statusClass xsi:type="xsd:string">Open</statusClass> 
  <submittedByFullname xsi:type="xsd:string">Anon User</submittedByFullname> 
  <submittedByUsername xsi:type="xsd:string">anon_user</submittedByUsername> 
  <submittedDate xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2013-01-31T10:27:13.000Z</submittedDate> 
  <title xsi:type="xsd:string">SWAPS Heatmap</title> 
  <trackerIcon xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <version xsi:type="xsd:int">100</version> 
  </multiRef>
  <multiRef id="id7" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns7:SoapFieldValues" xmlns:ns7="http://schema.open.collab.net/sfee50/soap60/type" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <names soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[14]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">BRD Received</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">Dev Started</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">EUDA Registered</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">Prioritised   Pending Dev</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">Product</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">Product Group</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">Requestor POC</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">Signed Off</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">UAT Delivered</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">UAT Delivery Date</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">VP Approval</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">BMSC POC</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">$fild306322$Coverage</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">$fild306551$test</names> 
  </names>
  <types soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[14]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">String</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">String</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">String</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">User</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">User</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">User</types> 
  </types>
  <values soapenc:arrayType="xsd:anyType[14]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
  <values xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2013-01-30T08:00:00.000Z</values> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="soapenc:string">Synthetics</values> 
  <values xsi:type="soapenc:string">GPF</values> 
  <values xsi:type="soapenc:string" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2013-01-30T08:00:00.000Z</values> 
  <values xsi:type="soapenc:string">anon_user</values> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  </values>
  </multiRef>
  <multiRef id="id8" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns8:SoapFieldValues" xmlns:ns8="http://schema.open.collab.net/sfee50/soap60/type" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <names soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[14]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">BRD Received</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">Dev Started</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">EUDA Registered</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">Prioritised   Pending Dev</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">Product</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">Product Group</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">Requestor POC</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">Signed Off</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">UAT Delivered</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">UAT Delivery Date</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">VP Approval</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">BMSC POC</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">$fild306322$Coverage</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">$fild306551$test</names> 
  </names>
  <types soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[14]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">String</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">String</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">String</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">User</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">User</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">User</types> 
  </types>
  <values soapenc:arrayType="xsd:anyType[14]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
  <values xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2013-01-31T08:00:00.000Z</values> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="soapenc:string">Synthetics</values> 
  <values xsi:type="soapenc:string">GPF</values> 
  <values xsi:type="soapenc:string" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2013-01-31T08:00:00.000Z</values> 
  <values xsi:type="soapenc:string">anon_user</values> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  </values>
  </multiRef>
  <multiRef id="id6" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns9:SoapFieldValues" xmlns:ns9="http://schema.open.collab.net/sfee50/soap60/type" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <names soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[14]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">BRD Received</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">Dev Started</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">EUDA Registered</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">Prioritised   Pending Dev</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">Product</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">Product Group</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">Requestor POC</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">Signed Off</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">UAT Delivered</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">UAT Delivery Date</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">VP Approval</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">BMSC POC</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">$fild306322$Coverage</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">$fild306551$test</names> 
  </names>
  <types soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[14]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">String</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">String</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">String</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">User</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">User</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">User</types> 
  </types>
  <values soapenc:arrayType="xsd:anyType[14]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
  <values xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2013-02-01T08:00:00.000Z</values> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="soapenc:string">Synthetics</values> 
  <values xsi:type="soapenc:string">GPF</values> 
  <values xsi:type="soapenc:string" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2013-02-01T08:00:00.000Z</values> 
  <values xsi:type="soapenc:string">anon_user</values> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  </values>
  </multiRef>
  <multiRef id="id5" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns10:SoapFieldValues" xmlns:ns10="http://schema.open.collab.net/sfee50/soap60/type" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <names soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[14]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">BRD Received</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">Dev Started</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">EUDA Registered</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">Prioritised   Pending Dev</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">Product</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">Product Group</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">Requestor POC</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">Signed Off</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">UAT Delivered</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">UAT Delivery Date</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">VP Approval</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">BMSC POC</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">$fild306322$Coverage</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">$fild306551$test</names> 
  </names>
  <types soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[14]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">String</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">String</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">String</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">User</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">User</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">User</types> 
  </types>
  <values soapenc:arrayType="xsd:anyType[14]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
  <values xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2013-02-01T08:00:00.000Z</values> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="soapenc:string">Synthetics</values> 
  <values xsi:type="soapenc:string">GPF</values> 
  <values xsi:type="soapenc:string" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2013-02-01T08:00:00.000Z</values> 
  <values xsi:type="soapenc:string">anon_user</values> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  </values>
  </multiRef>
  </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

All this only represents 4 records from a TeamForge CollabNet site.

I can see the "structure" as such.  The path, `/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/multiRef/dataRows` contains the 4 references to the 4 records in the odd format `<dataRows href="#id1" />`.

Then using the href id, you go to a path such as this one:

```
/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/multiRef (where the id attribute matches the record)
```

At this node, I want to be able to pick out a number of elements such as
"assignedToFullname", "title", etc.

However, within this node is an element called "flexFields" and looks like this:

```
<flexFields href="#id6" />
```

This is because in CollabNet you can have a number of custom fields.  So following the same rule as before, the flexfield info is located at:

```
/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/multiRef (where the id attribute matches the flexfield href)
```

A snippet of this XML for one record is as follows:

```
<multiRef id="id7" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns7:SoapFieldValues" xmlns:ns7="http://schema.open.collab.net/sfee50/soap60/type" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <names soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[14]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">BRD Received</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">Dev Started</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">EUDA Registered</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">Prioritised   Pending Dev</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">Product</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">Product Group</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">Requestor POC</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">Signed Off</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">UAT Delivered</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">UAT Delivery Date</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">VP Approval</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">BMSC POC</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">$fild306322$Coverage</names> 
  <names xsi:type="xsd:string">$fild306551$test</names> 
  </names>
  <types soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[14]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">String</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">String</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">String</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">User</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">User</types> 
  <types xsi:type="xsd:string">User</types> 
  </types>
  <values soapenc:arrayType="xsd:anyType[14]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
  <values xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2013-01-30T08:00:00.000Z</values> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="soapenc:string">Synthetics</values> 
  <values xsi:type="soapenc:string">GPF</values> 
  <values xsi:type="soapenc:string" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2013-01-30T08:00:00.000Z</values> 
  <values xsi:type="soapenc:string">anon_user</values> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <values xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:nil="true" /> 
  </values>
  </multiRef>
```

Is it in any way possible to use SQL Server to get this out to one table with a number of specified elements as columns *plus* the fledFields and their values as columns.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

**Update**
OK so far I've managed to get the normal data out from the XML file as follows:

```
SELECT T.c.value('@id','varchar(5)') as [id]
    , T.c.value('title[1]','varchar(255)') as [Title]
    , T.c.value('id[1]','varchar(255)') as [Artifact]
    , T.c.value('priority[1]','varchar(255)') as [Priority]
    , T.c.value('assignedToFullname[1]','varchar(255)') as [Assignee]
    , T.c.value('status[1]','varchar(255)') as [Status]
    , T.c.value('statusClass[1]','varchar(255)') as [statusClass]
    , T.c.value('folderTitle[1]','varchar(255)') as [Tracker]
    , Replace(T.c.value('flexFields[1]/@href','varchar(255)'),'#','') as [flexFieldsID]
FROM @xml.nodes('declare namespace soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
/soapenv:Envelope[1]/soapenv:Body[1]/multiRef') T(c)
WHERE T.c.value('@id','varchar(5)') IN
    (SELECT Replace(DR.h.value('@href','varchar(5)'),'#','') as [DataRowID]
    FROM @xml.nodes('declare namespace soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
    /soapenv:Envelope[1]/soapenv:Body[1]/multiRef/dataRows/dataRows') DR(h))
```

However, this looks hideous and I wondered if someone might know of a more elegant way.  I am also stuck on how to append the "flexFields" to the end of this results table.

**Further Update** 
I think I'm so close, but I cannot figure out how to get the flexFields into a "flat" table, because there's no structural link between the "Names" and the "Values", it's simply matched on the order by the look of it, so the first Name is the field name of the first Value, and so on, I just can't figure out how to write a query to do this.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server provides OPENXML method to fetch data from XML that can be inserted into any table or temporary table. 
example:

```
    DECLARE @idoc int
DECLARE @doc varchar(1000)
SET @doc ='
<ROOT>
<Customer CustomerID="VINET" ContactName="Paul Henriot">
   <Order CustomerID="VINET" EmployeeID="5" OrderDate="1996-07-04T00:00:00">
      <OrderDetail OrderID="10248" ProductID="11" Quantity="12"/>
      <OrderDetail OrderID="10248" ProductID="42" Quantity="10"/>
   </Order>
</Customer>
<Customer CustomerID="LILAS" ContactName="Carlos Gonzlez">
   <Order CustomerID="LILAS" EmployeeID="3" OrderDate="1996-08-16T00:00:00">
      <OrderDetail OrderID="10283" ProductID="72" Quantity="3"/>
   </Order>
</Customer>
</ROOT>'
--Create an internal representation of the XML document.
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc
-- Execute a SELECT statement that uses the OPENXML rowset provider.
SELECT    *
FROM       OPENXML (@idoc, '/ROOT/Customer',1)
            WITH (CustomerID  varchar(10),
                  ContactName varchar(20))
```

For detail you can refer:
[OPENXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276847%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

The only problem I see in this approach is your sample XML have a lot of escape/invalid characters for reading xml. For this you have to replace  your XML in intermediate PL/SQL using REPLACE to some valid character so that you can fetch values from XML to table. Sorry for incomplete response, I am a little busy right now to provide actual working Query. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I've read that I shouldn't use OPENXML and since I'm using SQL Server 2005 I should use XQuery instead.  I have tried it but still couldn't get anything better than what I've posted in my updated question.

Comment: If you can done in XQuery nothing is better. OPENXML works fine in SQL Server 2005. Also by your requirements it seems the process is one time or batch process (no user intervention).

Comment: Overall, I'm looking at using VBA to query the web service (CollabNet), pass the XML response to SQL Server and have it process/parse it, rather than using loops and such in VBA.  I'm not yet certain on how I'm going to store the data, it'll probably be in tables in SQL Server.  Also, we will be migrating to SQL Server 2008 soon, if that has any bearing on usage of OPENXML.